# TexStudio - internal embedded pdf viewer shows different figure than external pdf viewer of the output pdf

Tags: pdftex, pdf, texstudio, viewers

I use TexStudio (2.9.4) on a Mac OSX (10.10.3) with TexLive. The problem here is that when I insert figures, that are saved as pdf files, and compile with PDFLaTex, the output figures deviate from the input figures in the internal embedded pdf viewer. Links for figures are here: [Teil_A_Helium](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sygblzrxfr5kqpu/Teil_A_Helium.pdf?dl=0), [Teil_A_Luft](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dn0b7ye3egw5oys/Teil_A_Luft.pdf?dl=0). The MWE looks as follows:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Teil_A_Helium.pdf}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Teil_A_Luft.pdf}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The output pdf in the external pdf viewer (Preview) looks like this:

[image: external pdf view]

The output pdf in the embedded pdf viewer looks like this:

[image: embedded pdf view]

As you can see the figures are not the same. In the embedded pdf viewer all numbers and the experimentally measured dots are missing. Is there a solution to this problem?

Edit: I could not solve the problem. These are my settings under `Editor`, maybe someone can see the problem:
[image: editor settings]

Comment: It works right here using TeXlive 2014 on Linux with TeXstudio 2.9.4.

Comment: Your pdf figure does not contain the fonts embedded. In my case, Helvetica was substituted by Nimbus Sans. So I guess that the pdf viewer from TeXstudio can not load some fonts.

Comment: It's a pity TeXstudio does not substitute fonts automatically. If you might know how to fix the problem, please let me know. What editor do you use?

Comment: I use TeXstudio 2.9.4 but on Linux.

Comment: it substitutes, otherwise I would have problem to see your document. But in mt case, it works well.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.